# How to not show negative numbers in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have this code (it works):

```
SELECT sportsID, newsID, cID, SUM(likes) AS totalLikes 
FROM like_table 
GROUP BY sportsID, newsID 
ORDER BY totalLikes DESC
```

I tried to modify it to not show negative values, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT sportsID, newsID, cID, SUM(likes) AS totalLikes 
FROM like_table 
WHERE totalLikes > 0 
GROUP BY sportsID, newsID 
ORDER BY totalLikes DESC
```

Can anyone help? I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT sportsID, newsID, cID, SUM(likes) AS totalLikes 
FROM like_table 
GROUP BY sportsID, newsID
HAVING SUM(likes)> 0 
ORDER BY totalLikes DESC
```

**Explanation:**

The `HAVING` clause was added to SQL because the `WHERE` keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

The `WHERE` clause places conditions on the selected columns, whereas the `HAVING` clause places conditions on groups created by the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you. Provided answer, and syntax explanation!

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE totalLikes > 0` should be `HAVING SUM(likes) > 0` and be placed after the GROUP BY clause. Thus:

```
SELECT sportsID, newsID, cID, SUM(likes) AS totalLikes
FROM like_table 
GROUP BY sportsID, newsID 
HAVING SUM(likes) > 0 
ORDER BY totalLikes DESC
```

Comment: Can't accept, two answers, but I'll vote you up for the support :)